# What is the proper way to form this SQL statement?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a news database table that has two kinds of articles in it: social and official (mutually exclusive).

What I would like to do is reduce the number of social rows in the table to a specific number, while leaving the official news articles alone.

Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
DELETE
FROM News
WHERE _id NOT IN
    (SELECT _id
     FROM News
     WHERE IsOfficialNews=0
     ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 20

     UNION SELECT _id
     FROM News
     WHERE IsOfficialNews=1)
```

However, I get an error that states `ORDER BY clause should come after UNION not before`.  Moving the `ORDER BY` to the end of the inner `SELECT` results in `LIMIT clause should come after UNION not before`.

I understand the error message but I wonder if there is some other way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.  If I move the `LIMIT` clause to the end of the inner `SELECT` then I will still have more than 20 social rows left in the table (because it will also count official rows).

Comment: I'm still wondering what exactly you wanna do. 1. You do NOT want to delete any "official"-Rows. 2. You want to delete ALL "not official"-Rows , except for the - let's say - newest 20 ones. Is that correct?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Is there a way to turn that around? I mean something like:
DELETE FROM News
WHERE IsOfficialNews=0
AND ( _id NOT IN ( <select first 20 here> ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe like this (see comment above):

```
DELETE FROM News
WHERE IsOfficialNews=0
AND _id NOT IN
(SELECT _id
 FROM News
 WHERE IsOfficialNews=0
 ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 20)
```